# Using MapServer with ESRI enterprise geodatabase on Oracle

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, mapserver, oracle-dbms

I've been looking into MapServer, but can't find anything indicating that it can connect to an ESRI enterprise geodatabase (version 10.3 or 10.4) for vector data. There is [ArcSDE support](http://www.mapserver.org/input/vector/arcsde.html) but it's limited to version 9.2.

Is there any known path to serving vector data from an enterprise geodatabase on Oracle that uses the ESRI ST_GEOMETRY format?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able use the [OGR](http://www.mapserver.org/input/vector/ogr.html) connection, for reading ArcSDE.  The GDAL/OGR pages for the [ESRI SDE](http://www.gdal.org/drv_sde.html) driver, tells us:

> The driver has been tested with ArcSDE 9.x, and should work with newer versions, as well as ArcSDE 8.2 or 8.3. Both 2D and 3D geometries are supported.

Comment: As of 10.3, [ArcSDE is out of the picture](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2015/02/11/where-is-the-install-for-arcsde-10-3/). The [OGR test script](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/ogr/ogr_sde.py) referenced at the GDAL/OGR page connects to ArcSDE as opposed to Oracle (or whatever) directly. For this reason I don't see how it could work.